# How to get SQL Server stored procedure output parameter C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this code so how to get out parameter value here...

```
string Proc_CreateWorkingSet = "usp_CustomerInfo";

var parameters = new[] {
          new SqlParameter(){ ParameterName="@WorkTableName", Value="WorkingSet" },
          new SqlParameter(){ ParameterName="@ProcessName", Value=Customer.ProcessName },
          new SqlParameter(){ ParameterName="@SettingName", Value="NORTHSHOREMISCFIELD" },                            
          new SqlParameter(){ ParameterName="@ReturnedSQLCmd", Value=string.Empty, Direction=ParameterDirection.Output},
         };

ClientDatabase.ExecuteStoredProcedureNonQuery(Proc_CreateWorkingSet, parameters);
Logger.LogInfo(parameters[3].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: The problem most probably lies in your customized `ExecuteStoredProcedureNonQuery` which does something with parameters. No other ideas yet.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `Value` property like below. `ToString()` returns the parameter name and not value

```
Logger.LogInfo(parameters[3].Value);
```